# Do you could use python in ubuntu phone?

Tags: application-development, python, ubuntu-touch

They will be able to create applications for the Ubuntu Phone with python language

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu ! Can you be a little more specific in your question ? If I get you right, you want to know if Python will be available for application development on Ubuntu Phone. Is that right ? Take time to be clearer and more specific in your question to get better answers

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but not encouraged.  The Python runtime consumes a lot of memory, which is very limited on mobile devices.  Instead we offer an easy yet powerful solution in the form of QML, which uses simple UI declarations to build beautiful interface, Javascript to build functionality and logic into it, and it's all executed by Qt executables which make them much more efficient.

See http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started/ for more information